# How and where validate ownership of resource in spring boot rest delete endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

I am writing simple spring boot rest application and i come up with little architecture problem while creating DELETE endpoint. I have try way to solve this problem and I need advice which one is better and why.

First of all, I have class annoted with `@ControllerAdvice` which contains exception handlers:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(ex.getMessage());
}

@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotAccessException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleResourceNotAccessException(ResourceNotAccessException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED).body(ex.getMessage());
}
```

So i want to create endpoint :

```
@DeleteMapping("/{offerId}")
public void deleteOffer(@PathVariable Long offerId, Authentication authentication) {
// here code to delete offer.
}
```

So the main assumption is that logged user can delete offer which id is equals to offeId and he is owner of that offer (ownership i can check using code : `offer.getOwner().getUsername().equals(authentication.getName());` ) or has Role.ADMIN

I figure out three ways to do this:

### **First**

All logic in controller and only simple method

```
@DeleteMapping("/{offerId}")
public void deleteOffer(@PathVariable Long offerId, Authentication authentication) {
    AbstractOffer offer = offerService.findOfferById(offerId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Offer with given Id doesn't exists."));
    if (!offerService.isOwner(offer,authentication)) throw new ResourceNotAccessException("Cannot delete offer if you aren't owner");
    offerService.deleteOffer(offer);
}
```

### Second

Logic to remove this resource put into either `PermissionEvaluator` or validate using SPeL and annotation `@PreAuthorize(...)` In this case i am not throwing any exception and there is not called ControllerAdvice

`

### Third

Put all logic into service class and from controller only call this method.

```
@Service
public class OfferService {
.
.
.
public void deleteOfferIfOwner(Long offerId,Authentication authentication) {
    AbstractOffer offer = findOfferById(offerId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Offer with given Id doesn't exists."));
    if(!isOwner(offer,authentication)) throw new ResourceNotAccessException("Cannot delete offer if you aren't owner");
    deleteOffer(offer);
}
.
.
}
```

Then:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{offerId}")
public void deleteOffer(@PathVariable Long offerId, Authentication authentication) {
    offerService.deleteOfferIfOwner(offerId,authentication);
}
```

### Summary

In my opinion first solution is good because exception are connected to controller and are translated to response but i am not sure how much logic should i put into controller and how in this scenario validate if Authentication is admin.

The second one - not sure what to say, for me it is too complicated and i had to inject service class to validation classes or annotation (not sure if it is good practice) but it should work.

Third one - I am putting all logic into service and throwing 2 exception which are RUNTIME EXCEPTION and are connected to controller and controllerAdvice because on those exception depends result of calling endpoint.

I would be glad for some tips how to proper solved this and any feedback about code and project architecture. 
Most of the current code is available here:
[Github](https://github.com/hadson172/springwebapp/)

Comment: Every found a "Spring way" to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The way I am handling this in my apps resembles both your 1st and 3rd way but with a little twist.

More specifically I use a custom-made class `ResourceAccessHelper` and put inside all the code that validates user access rights to a resource or throws an exception if the user does not meet the criteria required.

```
/**
 * Helper class for checking whether a user has certain access rights to a resource during an HTTP
 * request.
 *
 * @author Thanos Psaridis
 */
@Component
public class ResourceAccessHelper {

  private final RolesHelper rolesHelper;

  /**
   * Constructor accepting {@link RolesHelper}
   *
   * @param rolesHelper Helper class for checking user Roles
   */
  @Autowired
  public ResourceAccessHelper(RolesHelper rolesHelper) {
    this.rolesHelper = rolesHelper;
  }

  /**
   * Getter for {@link RolesHelper}
   *
   * @return {@link RolesHelper}
   */
  public RolesHelper getRolesHelper() {
    return rolesHelper;
  }

  /**
   * Verifies that the given parameters are true by Checking user access by course id
   *
   * @param userEmail user email
   * @param courseId the course id the user may have access to
   * @throws AccessDeniedException in case user does not have access to this course id
   */
  public final void checkAccess(@NotNull final String userEmail, long courseId)
      throws AccessDeniedException {
    checkCourseDaoAccess(userEmail, courseId);
  }
  /**
   * Custom logic for checking whether a user can pass certain constraints given a courseId.
   *
   * @param userEmail user email
   * @param courseId the course id the user may have access to
   * @throws AccessDeniedException in case the access requirements are not met.
   */
  private void checkCourseDaoAccess(@NotNull String userEmail, long courseId)
      throws AccessDeniedException {
    if (isSuperAdmin(userEmail)) return;

    final AppUser appUser = rolesHelper.getUser(userEmail);

    if (isAdmin(userEmail)) {
      final List<Course> tenantCourses = appUser.getTenant().getCourses();

      final Optional<Course> optional =
          tenantCourses.stream().filter(course -> course.getId().equals(courseId)).findAny();

      if (optional.isPresent()) return;
    }

    if (isStudent(userEmail)
        && appUser
            .getEnrolments()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(enrolment -> enrolment.getCourse().getId().equals(courseId))) return;
    throw new AccessDeniedException("ACCESS DENIED");
  }
}
```

Then I would call the above class followed by your service class that deletes the resource in the controller by wrapping those in a try-catch block like so.

```
 try {
      // check access beforehand
      resourceAccessHelper.checkAccess(principalObject.getEmail(), givenCourseId);
      //proceed with the deletion of course.
      courseService.deleteCourse(givenCourseId)
 } catch (AccessDeniedException ignored) {
      //handle your exception here by sending a 404 response error or something similar
 }
```