# What is the best way to validate ownership of resource in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I was wondering how to check if a logged-in user is the owner of a resource during UPDATE and DELETE operations, and I came across a few methods, but these two seem good to me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56872544/21960620

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53030280/21960620

CompanyDto class

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompanyDto {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String companyName;

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    private AppUserDto adminProfile;

}
```

CompanyController class:

```
    @PutMapping("/companies/{companyId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateCompany(@PathVariable("companyId") Long companyId,
                                              @RequestBody @Validated CompanyDto companyDto) {

        CompanyDto updatedCompany = companyService.updateCompany(companyId, companyDto);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
```

And in my case, helper would look more or less like this?:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ResourceAccessHelper {

    private final CompanyService companyService;

    public boolean checkCompanyOwnership(Long companyId, Authentication authentication) {

        CompanyDto companyDto = companyService.getCompanyById(companyId);

        return companyDto.getAdminProfile().getUsername().equals(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if method `companyService.getCompanyById(companyId)` is OK here because it looks for Company and if it's not found then throws exception. However, `companyService.updateCompany(companyId, companyDto)`
also does that, so I'm not sure if it's ok.

Which of these methods is better? Or is there any other, better way?

Comment: The first answer externalizes the decision from the controller method, which is usually the recommended approach. Other than that, this seems like an opinion based question. Please give details about your specific problem and what you've tried (that isn't working).

Comment: For me the first answer seems better too, but you should consider regarding truth of incoming 'creator' param

Comment: You are asking "is xyz OK?" without trying it first. Please try the answer you have selected and update with the results of the test if you still have a question.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg It works just fine. I was just wondering "if fetching Company twice is ok" or "fetching object before method is even called is ok", but I found out that in JPA this object will be cached, so it will be fetched only one time.